# Nvidia GTX 1660Ti Code 43 on Device Manager

Tags: graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Before we start, specs:

OS: Win 11 Home 22H2 (22621.1702). My current OS is installed from the [Windows 11 Installation Media](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) on a USB

GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Internal) + Nvidia GTX 1660Ti (External, the cause of the issues)

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz

Memory: 512 SSD + 2TB HDD (exact drive type unknown, factory drives, I can find out if need be)

RAM: 16Gb (exact brand unknown, factory RAM)

BIOS Version: Insyde Corp. V2.06, 19/08/2021

Model: Acer Nitro AN515-55

Please let me know if more information is required, I will do my best to provide it.

---

In early May, my laptop blackscreened without notice, and I took it to a repair shop for repairs. After the repairs were complete (which involved replacing a burned chip, whose purpose I had sadly forgotten and the repair guy said was unrelated to the GPU), I tested the laptop and saw my GPU was missing in the Task Manager (it still is).

[image: Performance in Task Manager]

I looked at the Device Manager and I saw this issue: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

[image: Device properties]

I disabled and re-enabled the device, and I saw this: This device is working properly.

The GPU still did not exist on the Task Manager Performance list, so I restarted the laptop. After restarting, I rechecked the Device Manager and saw the Code 43 had persisted. I attempted to open Nvidia Control Panel. I received no response from the Control Panel. I tried everything in this [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/nvidia-control-panel-not-opening-windows-11/) (run in admin, End NVIDIA Background Processes, Restart NVIDIA Display Container Service, Repair & Reset the NVIDIA Control Panel App, Update Nvidia Drivers) to no success of reopening the Nvidia Control Panel, though I was successful in opening the software license agreement for the Control Panel.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version of my GPU's driver, both from GeForce Experience and [Nvidia directly](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/204244/en-us/), both with an express download and a custom download where I used a clean install to clean previous drivers. All download attempts were successful, with the installer not reporting any issues.

On GeForce Experience, I also encountered this screen, stating that "No driver found: Click continue to install the latest Game Ready driver or Studio driver".

[image: NVidia GeForce Experience]

I attempted to reset my laptop, first with the internal "reset PC" function with the documents retained. Then I attempted to reset with the documents deleted.

[image: Recovery settings]

It did not help.

My final attempt involves downloading the [Windows 11 Installation Media](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) on a USB and clean installing Windows from there. I followed [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-do-clean-install-windows-11) for my clean installation, with the only deviation being that instead of clearing the partition of only the system hard drive, I also cleared the partition of the external HDD.

It also did not help and I had to re-partition the external HDD. I restarted the laptop and there was no improvement.

Please let me know if more information is required to resolve this issue.

Comment: Get in touch with the repair guys and demand that they fix this new problem that they caused.

Comment: That is being done. In the meantime, I would like to solve this new problem since it will be a long weekend where I am.

Comment: Reseating the GPU while cleaning the contacts is just about the maximum that can be done for a non-professional.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give an update on this problem. I'm experiencing similar issues with my Victus 16. Can't open Nvidia Control panel, code 43, very little information being shown when using GPU-z.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).